# How could one interrupt handler go until the same source is free?

Tags: operating-system, x86, kernel, interrupt

Note that a single interrupt source (timer, keyboard, etc.) 
will not signal a new interrupt to the processor until 
the processor has indicated that handling of the previous interrupt from that source is ``done'', even if the system-wide interrupt-enable flag is on.

Who tells the PIC the current interrupt is over, and what does "systerm-wide interrupt-enable flag" mean?

Answer (score 1):

That has been covered in my comment in the other question. :)

OK... Some more details...

If we're talking about the PIC and its usual operation (as in the BIOS and DOS), there are 16 IRQ lines. They are mapped (in the PIC) to interrupt vectors **8 through 0Fh** (**IRQ0 through IRQ7**) and **70h through 77h** (**IRQ8 through IRQ15**).

By reprogramming the PIC you can change this assignment (see the PIC (**8259** chip) documentation). Changing this assignment is often more than just desirable in protected mode because various important exceptions are hardwired to interrupt vectors from **0** to around **1Fh** (e.g. the general protection exception (AKA **#GP**) is at vector **0Dh**, which is **IRQ5** in this default assignment).

**IRQ0** is the periodic timer (AKA **PIT**)
**IRQ1** is the keyboard
**IRQ2** is used to **chain 2nd PIC** (every PIC handles at most 8 IRQs, so you have 2 for 16 IRQs; IRQ8 thorugh 15 are, in fact, delivered through this IRQ2)
**IRQ3** and **IRQ4** are used for COM1 and COM2 serial ports
**IRQ6** is used for the FDD
**IRQ7** is used for the parallel port (where we used to connect our printers, and now it's usually the USB port)
**IRQ8** is used for another timer, the real-time clock (AKA **RTC**)
**IRQ12** is normally used for the PS/2 mouse
**IRQ14 and IRQ15** are used for HDDs/CDROMs

Other IRQs aren't very fixed.

The PIC itself is connected to the CPU at I/O ports 20h and 21h (PIC1) and 0A0h and 0A1h (PIC2).

The CPU signals completion of IRQ handling by sending the `EOI` command to the corresponding PIC, from where this IRQ has come.

Thus, for **IRQ0 through IRQ7** the ISR typically ends with this code:

```
...
mov al, 20h
out 20h, al ; send EOI to PIC1
; restore al using pop or mov
iret
```

For **IRQ8 through IRQ15** the same thing looks like this:

```
mov al, 20h
out 0a0h, al ; send EOI to PIC2
out 20h, al ; send EOI to PIC1
; restore al using pop or mov
iret
```

In this latter case every PIC gets an EOI because, as I mentioned it earlier, PIC2 doesn't deliver IRQs directly to the CPU, but rather through PIC1 (on PIC1's IRQ2; this effectively limits the number of IRQs to 15), so both PICs are involved. And PIC2 is an interrupt source to PIC1 just like, say, the keyboard. So, 2 EOIs.

Further, some devices (may) have their own equivalents of `EOI`. For example, XT keyboards waited for a bit pulse (from 1 to 0) in one of their registers as an indication that the keyboard interrupt handling is complete. In such cases you send `EOIs` to the device and PIC(s).

**EDIT**: Most likely the [text](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/p1/proj1.html) you're referring to means `FLAGS.IF` by "system-wide interrupt-enable flag".